# Is there an inbuilt API or NuGet package to read all assembly binding redirects from the runtime section of current applications app config file?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET framework 4.8 console application written in C#, with an app config file that contains several assembly binding redirects. I want to read all these binding redirects and extract the assembly name, version number, public key token and culture.

One solution is to just read the app config as an XML file and use XPATH to extract these details but I was wondering if there's an easier built in API or some Nuget package for this?

The System.Configuration namespace has a COnfigurationManager class but I don't think it allows reading the runtime section. I did try this:

```
var runtime = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("runtime")
```

But it returned NULL.